# Not able to create an SNS application endpoint using lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-js

In this code, the below method is not working at all. Not event throwing any error, nothing getting printed in the logs. Any suggestion on this?

```
const response = await snsClient.send(command,(err,data)=>{
});
```

Complete Code

```
import { SNSClient, CreatePlatformEndpointCommand } from  "@aws-sdk/client-sns";
const snsClient = new SNSClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
export  { snsClient };

export const handler = async (event,context) => {
  

var params = {
    PlatformApplicationArn: process.env.SNS_APP_ID, /* required */
    Token: event.DeviceToken, /* required */
    CustomUserData: 'UserId='+ event.ID
  };

try{
        const command = new CreatePlatformEndpointCommand(params);

        const response = await snsClient.send(command,(err,data)=>{
        if (err) 
        { 
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log(data);           // successful response
        }
        var endpointArn = response.EndpointArn;
        console.log(response);
        });

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        console.log("completed!");
    }
};
```